# Export GeoTIFFs issue on Google Earth Engine due to Gdal upgrade

Tags: export, gdal, google-earth-engine, geotiff

I exported my Geotiff images with Google Earth Engine. I used some metadata in these images for my python scripts but with the MAJ of 2023-05-04 (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/changelog) Google generates by default a BigTIFF without metadatas.
The new tiff images doesn't have any Exif file. Do you know how setting the BigTiff parameter to "False" ?

On the Gdal doc, we can change the BIGTIFF=[YES/NO/IF_NEEDED/IF_SAFER] but i dont know how can i do it on Google Earth Engine.

Thank you